# Firing up CloudFormationTemplate using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform

How to launch a CloudFormationTemplate from Terraform. Terraform has created VPC and SecurityGroups. How to pass in vpcID and SecurityGroupID into CFT. I have searched but couldn't find any links for the same. RTFM is not any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you should pass parameters to `aws_cloudformation_stack` resource.

```
resource "template_file" "redshift_cloudformation" {
  template = "${file("redshift.cloudformation")}"

  vars {
    redshift_public_subnet_id  = "${element(split(",", terraform_remote_state.shared.output.public_subnet_ids), 0)}"
    redshift_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.redshift.id}"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "heavy_redshift" {
  name          = "heavy-redshift"
  template_body = "${template_file.redshift_cloudformation.rendered}"

  parameters {
    MasterUsername     = "master"
    MasterUserPassword = "MasterPassword123"
  }
}
```

Check complete code for more examples - https://github.com/antonbabenko/terraform-aws-devops/blob/master/extra/heavy_cf_redshift.tf#L40-L48

Comment: Can you try to take some of the relevant information out of the link and have it directly in the answer? That way if your code changes then this answer may still be useful for others.